# Copy and paste pictures doesn't work

Tags: file-management

I'm a new user to Elementary OS 0.4 Loki, before this I was using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  I'm using a System 76 laptop with an Intel I5 processor and 16MB RAM.  I installed Crossover Linux and installed MS Office 2007.  Everything was working fine until I tried to copy and paste a picture taken with my camera into a Word document.  Instead of copying and pasting the picture itself, it brought over a string of the location of the file instead.  The way I was able to bring the picture into the document was by pressing "Import" in Word and selecting the picture.  The copy and paste option seems not to work.  Is this a bug or is there something that I'm doing wrong or need to install?

I also installed Libre Office Writer and had the same issues when copying and pasting a picture from my USB drive.  The same occurred when I saved the picture to the hard drive and did a copy and paste.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Copying from *Files* (`pantheon-files`) and pasting to LibreOffice does this indeed. You might want to file a feature request in `pantheon-files`: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+filebug

As a workaround, you can drag&drop pictures from *Files*: this works with LibreOffice (could not test with Crossover though).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've decided to go back to Ubuntu since the desktop is readily available for someone coming from Windows with little knowledge of Linux. In Ubuntu everything works from the get go. Thanks again.